# NHibernate query fails with "the multi-part identifier could not be bound" on an aggregate query

Tags: nhibernate

I'm trying to understand why this simple query is generating the wrong SQL on NHibernate 3.3:

```
var query = session.CreateQuery(@"select count(*) as C
                                  from Parent p
                                       inner join fetch p.Child c
                                  where c.Field = 'someValue'");
```

When I execute this query the generated SQL does NOT include a reference to the Child table, which causes the dreaded "the  multi-part identifier _child.FIELD could not be bound" exception.

Anyone has an idea on why this problem and how to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference, if someone else gets burned by this.

It seems the internals of NHibernate are filtering out join when generating the query.

So, the only solution we found was to rephrase the query this way:

```
select count(*) as C
from Parent p
where p.Child.Field = 'someValue'
```

This way, NHibernate is going to generate the join syntax (using cross join operators and where clauses).

Answer (score 0):

Assign a different alias to `count(*)`, probably nhibernate is getting confused since you're using `c` and `C` as aliases.

For instance, you could set your query like this

```
var query = session.CreateQuery(@"select count(*) as co
                              from Parent p
                                   inner join fetch p.Child c
                              where c.Field = 'someValue'");
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the problem. The generated sql is something like this: "SELECT COUNT(*) as C FROM PARENT _PARENT WHERE _CHILD.NAME = 'Some Value'" - which is clearly wrong.

Comment: @A.Chiesa: query seems pretty straight forward. Have you tried removing `count(*) as C` just for testing purposes? Just to check if error persist

Comment: yep. A select with the EXACT same from and where clauses works flawlessly. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: @A. Chiesa: sorry to insist, but you have tried change the `count` alias, right? As I told you, query seems really simple to hide many things.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't specify it, but yes, I changed the alias. My real-world query is more involved than this, but this is a bare bone query to highlight the problem. You can verify it by yourself: if you have an aggregate without group by clause, NH is not going to generate the joins in the from clause, apparently.